# red5 performance number of users

Tags: red5

I need to build infrastructure for video streaming service, that will be able to handle >100 live streams with average of 50 viewers, where top stream can have up to 5000 viewers. All streams will be served as multicast, not extra transcoding will be required (input and output will be h.264), no recording will be made. I'm curious how many streams can handle simple red5 server and how to calculate max of users.